# If mysql_num_rows is greater than 0

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get this statement to work... I'm checking to see if $batchid exist and if it does then stop process the script.

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select batch_id from load_test 
                    where batch_id='".$batchid."'")) > 0) {
    die("Error batch already present");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that $batchid is escaped with mysql_real_escape_string.

This code should work (non case-sensitive):

```
if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM load_test WHERE batch_id='".$batchid."'"), 0) > 0) {
    die("Error batch already present");
}
```

The case-sensitive version ([source](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/databases/mysql/f801.shtml)):

```
if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM load_test WHERE batch_id LIKE BINARY '".$batchid."'"), 0) > 0) {
    die("Error batch already present");
}
```

Comment: how can i modify it to be if result == 0 then do this... here's my example below but it's not working. if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM load_test WHERE           batch_id='".$batchid."' AND word='".$data[2]."'"), 0) < 0) { 
    mysql_query($importword);}

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to change the last operator from < to ==, because mysql_result should not return negative value, but zero or a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write :

```
$res=mysql_query("select count(*) from load_test where batch_id='".$batchid."'");
if($res>0)
{
           die("Error batch already present");
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make $bitchid compare to batch_id and be non-case sensitive?

Comment: you can use "like" clause for comparission.

Comment: hmm i just ran the query and i'm getting the die() message when the table is empty. so my following code to INSERT does not process. the count should be 0 since nothing is there hmm

Comment: @Kishan: `mysql_query()` does not return the result of the count, only a resource for later processing.  You need to call it, then call `mysql_result($res, 0)` to get the value of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: This is the code i'm using... doesn't seem to work.
$res=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM load_test WHERE batch_id=UCASE('".$batchid."')");
mysql_result($res, 0);
 if($res<0){
die("Error batch already present");
}

$importword="INSERT into load_test SET 
word = '".$data[2]."',
batch_id = UCASE('".$batchid."')";

Comment: sorry try:> instead of <.

$res=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM load_test WHERE batch_id=UCASE('".$batchid."')"); 
if($res>0){ die("Error batch already present"); }